# Deserializing Objects in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

What i have:

1. A WebAPI Service which contains the businesslogic and works with JSON
2. A client which sends requests to the WebAPI and waits for responses
3. An interface "IBusinesspartner" and 2 Objects which inherits from the interface: "Businesspartner" and "Potential".

What i need:

I need to deserialize an interface to JSON which contains some other custom objects.
Like this:
**IBusinesspartner**

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Street { get; set; }
public SalesDivision Division { get; set; }
public IDictionary<SalesDivison, Money> TurnoverPerDivision { get; set; }
```

What i already did:

i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base) thread to implement a custom converter which seems to work fine to deserialize the JSON String which i get as response from the WebAPI Service until it needs to deserialize the Dictionary.. then i get the following error message:

> Could not convert string 'BL.Service.Models.SalesDivision' to dictionary key type 'data.model.SAP.SalesDivision'. Create a TypeConverter to convert from the string to the key type object. Path 'TurnoverPerSalesDivision.BL.Service.Models.SalesDivision', line 1, position 17672.

the question:

yes i know the error message tells me what to do but i still don't explicit know what i have to do in my next step. Shall i rework / extend my just implemented converter for the IBusinesspartner interface or shall i create an own converter for each of my objects ? how could such a converter look like? any examples maybe? i would be happy about any help and information i can get.

Comment: Is SalesDivision decorated with DataContract and DataMember attributes? Those could be necessary for deserialization to take place correctly

Comment: no right now they are not. but that wouldn't be a problem to change that.

Comment: Also IDictionary could be a problem. What about replacing it with two arrays (SalesDivision[], Money[]), and re-creating it on the other side? (Looks terrible, I know.)

Comment: actually i don't want to change any logic. i think it should be possible with the JsonConverter

Comment: Try adding those so - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LorcanO'Neill ok i'll try that and tell you the result here, thanks